# Blog page won't show Blog template

Tags: templates, page-template

I set my "Blog" page to a Blog template I created in Pages (in the dashboard). Also, in Settings > Reading, I set my Home page (home template) as my Front page and my Blog page as my Posts page. However, when I navigate to my Blog page, it shows the home template. Yet, the body class of the Blog page is `blog logged-in`. I am confused. How can I make my Blog page show my Blog template?

I pasted my Blog template here for reference: http://pastebin.com/6ML30D7N

Comment: **1)** What is the **file name** of your blog custom page template? **2)** What is the **file name** of your front page custom page template? **3)** Can we see a **live link** to the site?

Comment: 1) blog.php 2) home.php 3) Client doesn't want it off maintenance right now but if the first two answers don't help, I can open it for a short while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> 1) **blog.php** What is the file name of your blog custom page template? 2) **home.php** What is the file name of your front page custom page template?

The answer is simple:

The `home.php` file name is a **reserved** file name in [the WordPress template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), and is used by the template hierarchy to render the **blog posts index**.

So, WordPress is doing exactly what you've told it to do. :)

Simple solution:

1. Rename `home.php` (your **Front Page** template) as **`front-page.php`**
2. Rename `blog.php` (your **blog posts index** template) as **`home.php`**

**Note**: you'll have no need to select either template explicitly, since WordPress will use both automatically. (You need only configure **`Settings -> Reading`** properly, which you've already done.) So, you can also:

- Remove the **`Template:`** PHP header tag from both files.